# Prepend a column to an array

Tags: python, list

I have an array in Python which I read from a text file:

```
["Engine", "Gearbox", "Tires", "Battery"]
```

I would like to make this a multidimensional array and prepend an identification tag, e.g. CAR. The result should look like this:

```
[["CAR", "Engine"], ["CAR", "Gearbox"], ["CAR", "Tires"], ["CAR", "Battery"]]
```

What is the fastest and most simple way to achieve this?

Comment: [...] is a List and not an array. Which one do you want to use? arrays require a library (like numpy) afaik

Comment: last option of my answer should be the slower, let me know if you have tested it!

Comment: Thank you very much. I took the first option. But you are right, maybe I should check which one is the fastest. Btw, that would be a cool follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be very careful! that variable does not contain an array, contains a list. (python doesn't support arrays by default).
this should be the answers to you question

#### use list comprehension – the most "pythonic" way to do this

```
l = ["Engine", "Gearbox", "Tires", "Battery"]
result = [['CAR',i] for i in l]
print(result)
```

```
[["CAR", "Engine"], ["CAR", "Gearbox"], ["CAR", "Tires"], ["CAR", "Battery"]]
```

#### use a for loop – the most simple way to do this

```
l,result = ["Engine", "Gearbox", "Tires", "Battery"],list()
for i in l:
   result.append(['CAR',i])
print(result)
```

```
[["CAR", "Engine"], ["CAR", "Gearbox"], ["CAR", "Tires"], ["CAR", "Battery"]]
```

#### use map() – the most cool way to do this

```
l = ["Engine", "Gearbox", "Tires", "Battery"]
f = lambda x: ['CAR', x]
result = list(map(f,l))
print(result)
```

```
[['CAR', 'Engine'], ['CAR', 'Gearbox'], ['CAR', 'Tires'], ['CAR', 'Battery']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension would be a pretty fast and simple way.

```py
lis = ["Engine", "Gearbox", "Tires", "Battery"]
new_list = [["CAR", x] for x in lis]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in one line:

```
l = ["Engine", "Gearbox", "Tires", "Battery"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

result = [["CAR", i] for i in l]
```

The result will be:

```
[['car', 'Engine'], ['car', 'Gearbox'], ['car', 'Tires'], ['car', 'Battery']]
```